# Where can I learn about the formal proof for the Riemann Sum / Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

In my calculus class, we started with some real analysis but the professor told us that this year he won't be going over the formal proof for the Riemann sum/integral. I looked it up and only found different proofs for Riemann properties as well as other concepts. Does anyone know what he may have been talking about? What are some resources I can use to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you are interested about, you'll find in Walter Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis".

Comment: And in Advanced Calculus, by Devinatz.